# Careers 2.0 cannot import some Google Code projects that I own

Tags: bug, status-deferred, jobs

I have two projects whose **owner** is me, and two more projects which I participated in.

Owned:

- https://code.google.com/p/mrcl/
- https://code.google.com/p/cciu-open-course-labs/
- https://code.google.com/p/tinycube/

Participated:

- https://code.google.com/p/anpshare/

But I cannot import `mrcl` and `cciu-open-course-labs` projects, and also Google Code profile only show the other two projects (`tinycube` and `anpsahre`) as "my" projects.
It might be a problem in Google Code, but I want to import whichever projects that I'm listed as either owner, committer or contributor.

Comment: Hi, what's the URL of your Google Code user page?

Comment: Here it is - https://code.google.com/u/daybreaker12/

Comment: This is [an ongoing issue](http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=5597) please echo your trouble to this support request.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid we are limited to what Google Code "tells" us are your projects on the user page. It does seem to be an inconsistency on their side. We'll reach out to the GC people and make an attempt at a workaround in the meantime.

If you can figure out a way to get that project listed under "Projects" on your user page, that would solve it. Maybe un-star the project and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to unstar the projects I own, but it did not help. I also think the problem lies on the Google side.